# Auth0 - get id_token from refresh_token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, auth0, refresh-token

In our 7+ microservices we rely on the Auth0 `id_token`. When exchanging a `refresh_token` (`POST myapp.auth0.com/oauth/token`) I only get back an `access_token` and not a `id_token`.

How do I exchange a `refresh_token` for an `id_token` with Auth0's API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the refresh token grant is for Auth0's new API Authorization feature. The endpoint I was looking for was `/delegation`.

Example Node.js code:

```
const tokenClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://${env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}`,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
})

const refreshTokenClient = {
  getAccessToken: (refreshToken) => {
    // The official Node.js SDK for Auth0 does not
    // support this it would seem (it forces passing id_token)
    return tokenClient.post('/delegation', {
      client_id: env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      target: env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
      scope: 'openid',
      api_type: 'auth0'
    }).then(r => r.data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically the `refresh_token` grant type is part of OAuth 2.0 and the `id_token` is part of OpenID Connect, an identity protocol built on top of OAuth 2.0.

The `refresh_token` grant type of OAuth 2.0 allows for renewing access tokens (only). OpenID Connect doesn't define additional behavior beyond that for a good reason: the `id_token` is defined as the result of a user authentication event and a "authentication refresh" without user interaction can thus not result in a new `id_token`. The user may have left, logged out or his/her account removed in the mean time.

Refreshing an `id_token` should be done by sending the user to the OpenID Connect Provider again, not by using a refresh token autonomously.

Comment: Can I get any Demo for the refresh token, for angular? @Hans